# "Where clause" is not working in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

[image: data sample]

I used AWS Glue Console to create a table from S3 bucket in Athena. You can see a relevant part on the screenshot above. I obfuscated column name, so assume the column name is `"a test column"`. I would like to select the records with value **D** in that column. The query I tried to run is:

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    "a test column" = "D"
```

Nothing is returned. I also tried to use **IS** instead of **=**, as well as to surround **D** with single quotes instead of double quotes within the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
-- Tried this
WHERE 
    "a test column" = 'D'

-- Tried this
WHERE 
    "a test column" IS "D"

-- Tried this
WHERE 
    "a test column" IS 'D'
```

Nothing works. Can someone help? Thank you.

The error message I got is

> Mismatched input 'where' expecting  (service: amazon athena; status code: 400; error code: invalid request exception; request id: 8f2f7c17-8832-4e34-8fb2-a78855e3c17d)

Comment: Believe that table and column names must be lower case and may not contain any special characters other than underscore. Can you control the column name?

Comment: Remove the quotes from around "a test column" - these are not needed in Athena

Comment: Can you give me what is the output of show create table <table-name> ?

Comment: The column name is automatically created by the Glue crawler, so there is space in the middle. That is why " " is needed around "a test column".

Comment: show create table <table-name> returns an error below -- Queries of this type are not supported (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: b08366a0-2eaf-4434-8ccf-eee473fa343b)

Comment: @L.Yang Have you substituted `<table-name>` with the actual name your table when you executed `show create table <table-name>`?

Comment: Yes I used real table name......

Comment: I am guessing some characters in the table is not letting you run the above query. Can you try on console clicking 3 dots against the table and click Generate create table DDL and find the actual column name and use same column name to run query as select * from table where "column_name" like '%D%'

Answer (score 18):

Problem with the query syntax. Use single quotes (') when you refer to a string values, because double quotes refer to a column name in your table.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    "column_name" = 'D'
```

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected answer (also apologize if I did not say it clearly in the original post) is that, I cannot add "limit 200" in front of the where clause. I have to add it in the end. Hope it helps others.

Comment: you didn't posted the full SQL query in your question?